# Change the background color of a Row in a listview when I vary the contents of a control bound to it

Tags: wpf, listview, background, bind, selecteditem

Ok this is my scenario.

I have a UserControl with a ListView and, for example, one TextBox bound to the ListView SelectedItem.

This works fine.

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="listviewUser"   
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">                             
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="User Name" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=UserName}" />                                
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<TextBox >
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding ElementName="listviewUser" 
               Path="SelectedItem.UserName" 
               ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
               Mode="TwoWay"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">                                   
      </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

But i want to change the background color of the row selected when the text value of my textbox changes.

I hope I have been concise and thousand pardons if this question was already settled (I'm not very good at English).

Thank you very much

Comment: Based on what criteria do you want to change it, and to what?

Comment: My criteria is:
 When the value of Text property change, change the Background color of the selectedItem in my ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions that you can choose.

1. If you want to change in a small set of colors, use DataTrigger at XAML.
   (note that the code below is not tested)

   ```
   <ListViewItem>
       <ListViewItem.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}" Value="passed">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                   </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}" Value="wrong">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </ListViewItem.Style>
   </ListViewItem>
   ```
2. Use DataTemplateSelector for more complex color selection.
   a good reference is: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector
3. Use event handler at the ItemTemplate. This is not recommended because you need to write at code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
I will try it now and then I tell if there is any problem

Comment: Ok. I am testing this solution but i found some problems:

1. The style should be setted in a GridViewColumn or in a ListViewItem?

Comment: Please try at ListViewItem. it will give a scope of row decoration. I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: arrrrrg. I can't find the right answer to my question.
I know that i need to use DataTrigger but i dont know how can use it, for example, in a resource dictionary.

ALL of my ListViewItems must implement this DataTrigger for ALL the textBoxes binded to it.

Thank you very much for all the efforts

Comment: Hardly understand your GUI and interaction requirement. Resource dictionary is just a refactoring issue. I mean, if you achieve your requirements inside of a ListViewItem.Style as above code, you surely packed up the Style elements to the resource dictionary.

Comment: Oh man sorry for taking so long to answer, i have managed do it because of your tips.